# Align method parameters with VS or R#

Tags: visual-studio, methods, parameters, alignment, resharper

I set some wrapping settings in Resharper but I can't figure out how to change this:

```
void Write(string Ludwig,
   string Von,
   string Mises)
{
}
```

to this:

```
void Write(string Ludwig,
           string Von,
           string Mises)
{
}
```

Comment: are you using Stylecop / Stylecop For Resharper by any chance? (http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I thought Stylecop is the formatting engine integrated in VS, isn't it?

Comment: That would be FxCop. StyleCop is similar but works on source code instead of binaries and add new settings on top of ReSharper.